# "not liked by almost any" vs. "not liked by almost all"

Tags: grammaticality

Given that almost all of Peter's classmates dislike him, which of the following version is correct, and which more common?

> Peter is not liked by almost any of his classmates.

versus

> Peter is not liked by almost all of his classmates.

Comment: I'm not sure about the first one but the second one is correct and more common.

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence

> Peter is not liked by almost any of his classmates.

maybe should be rephrased as

> Peter is not liked by any of his classmates.

Your second question is closer to the point you want to make

> Peter is not liked by almost all of his classmates.

but draws attention to the fact that there are some who still like him.

> Peter is not liked by **most** of his classmates.

would be closer to your ultimate meaning.